# What happened to George Fleming in Chuck?

Tags: plot-explanation, chuck

In the episode 'Chuck versus the Alma Mater', Chuck has a flashback to his university days. One person featuring heavily in them was Professor George Fleming, his Stanford professor, who kicked Chuck out of Stanford after he was framed by Bryce for cheating on a test. It was later revealed that Fleming was actually a CIA recruiter who had been ordered to recruit Chuck for the Omaha, except Bryce stopped him.

Later in the episode, assassin Magnus Einerson shoots him with a crossbow, causing Fleming to give Chuck a sheet of paper containing the location of his disk with the details of the students he had recruited. However it is never clarified what actually happens to him (at least, not up to where I've watched them). Sarah mentions that he has been taken to hospital, but she does not say whether or not he died.

So what actually happened, if known, to Fleming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While being unable to find something definitive, even after re-watching the episode, according to the [Chuck Wikia](http://chuck-nbc.wikia.com/wiki/George_Fleming), Fleming is dead.

> But before Fleming could tell Chuck why he was expelled, Einerson
>   shoots him in the back with his crossbow.

No further information is found after being told by Sarah that he's headed into surgery, which would strongly suggest he's no longer alive.